# cast to SVGSVGElement from org.w3c.dom.Element fails

Tags: java, java-me, svg

Seriously, if I cast like this:

```
(SVGSVGElement) (((SVGImage)blabla).getDocument().getDocumentElement())
```

it works, but if I try

```
(SVGSVGElement)doc.getElementById(some_id)
```

I get cast error, but both getDocumentElement() and getElementById() returns the same type `org.w3c.dom.Element`, my global goal is to get the X-coordinates of some image on my svg-scene loaded from file, in order to zoom scene to make this image fit in visible area. I tried to achieve that with  `((SVGSVGElement)doc.getElementById(some_id)).getBBox().getX()` but you see what I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.w3c.dom.Element` is the one of the lowest intefaces in DOM architecture, and lots of class extend this, particular `SVGSVGElement`.

You need to figure out, what type is returned in `doc.getElementById(some_id)` and then do the casting according that information:

```
log.debug("Returned class is - " + doc.getElementById(some_id).getClass().getName();
//or
System.out.println("Returned class is - " + doc.getElementById(some_id).getClass().getName();
```

And the most easiest way is to try to know the type directly in the debugger.

And the only cases, which I know, that type seems to be right, but ClassCastException occurs:

- classloaders issues (when one class from 2 different libraries was loaded into 2 different classloaders)
- AOP proxy issue

Comment: in both cases it returns `com.nokia.mid.impl.isa.dom.svg.CBFSVGLocatableElement`

Comment: Then please check `cases`, which I described in the answer.